# Choosing the best URL key for categories

Tags: multistore, url, seo

I have a multi-language store and try to choose the best URL key for categories. Also note that it can be set only for all store views, for a multi-language store it is a problematic point because the URL key for categories is a global value.

Also I try to add the main key word in the URL path because the store sells just one type of products - paintings. I can use this key word in the URL key in all store languages, but maybe it is not such a good deal - for example painting-painture. Or should I add the key word in the end of the URL key for each product? Another solution is to keep it language independent and don't use at all the main key word in the path but just the artist name instead. What do you think about?

**Edit:**
Take a look to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/16431/3441) for an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about changing the scope of the url key just to storeview? So you can have a urlkey for every language, but be careful, the side effect is e.g. that you can't just change the storeview and stay in the category!

```
$installer->updateAttribute(
    'category',
    'urlkey', 
    'is_global', 
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE
);
```

Comment: Nice. And you can even overcome the side effect on change store view, by adding custom url rewrites. Something like: on store 2, for request `url_path_for_store_1` 301 redirect to `url_path_for_store_2`. And the other way around for store 1. although this gets messy and grows exponentially with every store view you add

Comment: Yes, but then you need to be sure, that the url_key is unique over all shops.